# How to determine whether or not some integration is divergent using NIntegrate in Mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am doing the following multi-dimensional integration using NIntegrate in Mathematica which is potentially divergent

```
Table[NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[1 - x1^2] Sqrt[1 - x2^2] Sqrt[1 - x3^2]*0.5/(-0.5^2 + 4 (x1 + x2 + x3)^2), 
{x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 6, MinRecursion -> 3,   Method -> rule],
{rule, {"GlobalAdaptive", "MultidimensionalRule", "NewtonCotesRule", "GaussKronrodRule", "ClenshawCurtisRule"}}]
```

This code gives the following result

> {-2931.89, -2931.89, 0.0756414, 0.0763179, 0.0752467}

Therefore I suspect that the integral is actually divergent. But how can I know it for sure? Is there any other way to check this further?

Comment: Look at the "messages" from NIntegrate, which indicate problems.

Comment: You can see if it converges with `Exclusions -> {x1 + x2 + x3 == 1/4}`.

Answer (score 2):

First, if possible use arbitrary-precision numbers.  Therefore, I changed $0.5$ to $1/2$.  That way, we can do the integration with increasing working precision:

```
Table[NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[1 - x1^2] Sqrt[1 - x2^2] Sqrt[
    1 - x3^2]*1/2/(-1/2^2 + 4 (x1 + x2 + x3)^2), {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 
   1}, {x3, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> wp], {wp, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}}]
```

{0.071384, 0.07138433254, 0.0713843325396655, 
0.071384332539665463073, 0.07138433253966546307254175, 
0.0713843325396654630725417501738}

Based on these results, it appears to be converging to a non-zero number.  You can of course add PrecisionGoal, AccuracyGoal, Methods, MaxRecursion, and increase the working precision further if you wish.